# Sorting by date a grouped query

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data table where I enter all my expenses and incomes.
I would like to group them using the query.

```
M   1000    income      12/02/2023
b   2000    income      12/03/2023
a   -400    spending    22/03/2023
d   2000    income      14/01/2023
b   -300    spending    12/01/2023
a   1000    income      12/08/2023
```

The query so far looks like this :

`=QUERY(A1:B6;"select A, sum(B), count(B) group by A";)`
The issue I have is that I would like to sort the query by date (from the first occurence, for exemple `b` would be first in row, followed by `d` then `M` then `a`.)

Is there a way I can do that?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FgeEmMcbiZf_VKRsQ2NzCS9yc8316qNJT6cRl5x_y4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within QUERY you could use MIN(D) to find the "smallest" date and sort the range by it:

```
=QUERY(A1:D;"select A, sum(B), count(B),MIN(D) where A is not null group by A order by MIN(D)";)
```

[image]

If you want, you can wrap it in another QUERY to get rid of that extra column:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:D;"select A, sum(B), count(B),MIN(D) where A is not null group by A order by MIN(D)";);
"Select Col1,Col2,Col3")
```

Comment: just one quick question, - out of context - but is there a way I can label 'sum', 'count', 'min' here ?

Comment: Yes, you can use LABEL indicating the precise operation of that column as in "Select" clause. For example: `=QUERY(A1:D;"select A, sum(B), count(B),MIN(D) where A is not null group by A order by MIN(D) label A 'Concept',sum(B) 'Total Sum', count(B) 'Count', MIN(D) 'First appearance'";)`